# Functional derivative of free energy

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I found a paper regarding the statistical field theory of electrolytes. In that paper, free energy functional is defined as
$F = F[\phi_a, \phi_c, \psi_e(\phi_a, \phi_c), \psi_a(\phi_a, \phi_c), \psi_c(\phi_a, \phi_c)]$.
They calculated $\delta F = 0$. By definition, how can I find functional derivative and make it work?

Comment: Which paper? Link to abstract page? Which page?

Comment: The paper name is "Modeling hydration-mediated ion-ion interactions in electrolytes
through oscillating Yukawa potentials" published in PRE.

Comment: Can I calculate like $\delta F = \sum_{\xi}(\delta F)/(\delta \xi) \delta \xi$, where $\xi = \phi_a , \phi_c , \psi_a, \psi_c, \psi_e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the section below Eq. (13). They did not calculate $\delta F=0$. It is the definition of equilibrium, that no infinitesimal field variation changes the free energy, meaning that the free energy is at a minimum.

To do the variational, replace $\phi_a$ and $\phi_c$ in all the expressions by $\phi_a+\delta\phi_a$ and $\phi_c+\delta \phi_c$, respectively, and keep only linear terms in the "$\delta$-fields" (i.e. just set all terms like $\delta \phi_a \delta \phi_c$ or $(\delta \phi_a)^2$ to zero). In the end, you will get something like this:
$$
F = F (\phi_a,\phi_c) + \int d^3 r (\textrm{Something}) \delta \phi_a +  \int d^3r (\textrm{Some other thing}) \delta \phi_c 
$$
These equations tell you by definition what the functional derivatives are
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_a} = (\textrm{Something})  
\qquad 
\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_c} = (\textrm{Some other thing})  
$$
These are each to be set to zero, then some mathematical tricks may be necessary (I don't know, haven't done it) to arrive at their Equation (14).